# Need help on xslt logic for translating element attributes into element

Tags: java, xml, xslt

My requirement is as follows

If any complex element contains only text then corresponding element attributes translate into element to parent level.

If any complex element contains children then corresponding element attributes translate into element to same element level.

This translation want to achieve using xslt logic.

Input XML

---

```
<root>
    <food name="desert">butter scotch</food>
    <special type="nonveg">
        <name>chicken</name>
    </special>
</root>
```

Output XML

---

```
<root>
<food>butter scotch</food>
<name>desert</name>
<special>
    <type>nonveg</type>
    <name>chicken</name>
</special>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start off with the Identity Transform....

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

For the rule "*If any complex element contains only text then corresponding element attributes translate into element to parent level*", you could use the following template (I am ignoring comments and processing-instuctions here, and just checking the element has no child element)

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*)][@*]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="toelement"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The template with mode "toelement" will turn the attribute to an element. (It will be re-used by the other rule).

```
    <xsl:template match="@*" mode="toelement">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

For the rule "*If any complex element contains children then corresponding element attributes translate into element to same element level.*" then you could actually match on the attribute directly:

```
<xsl:template match="*[*]/@*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="toelement"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="*[*]/@*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="toelement"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)][@*]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="toelement"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*" mode="toelement">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tim. But I have one more requirement and that is  for each attribute while translating to element need to append the its element name. For example as below                                              Input XML:
********************
<root>
    <food name="desert">butter scotch</food>
    <special type="nonveg">
        <name>chicken</name>
    </special>
</root>

Output XML
*********************
<root>
<food>butter scotch</food>
<food_name>desert</food_name>
<special>
    <special_type>nonveg</special_type>
    <name>chicken</name>
</special>
</root>

Comment: Tim,  Can you please respond?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NaveenPamulapati Tim's answer perfectly handled your question, the output is exactly as you laid it out in your question along with a good explanation. I recommend you accept this great answer and if you have a additional problems (outside the scope of the original question) you should ask a new question. I just happen to be sitting on this question when I left my computer and came back.

However to awnser your question just use the name of the parent node when selecting attributes `<xsl:element name="{name(..)}_{local-name()}">`

Comment: @NaveenPamulapati dont forget to accept this persons answer! (checkbox by the upvote option)

Comment: I had actually gone to bed when the original comment was made! Thank you to @ug_ to responding.